# Implementation method according to the Array and List type of `in` keyword

Tags: java, arrays, list, kotlin

I have a very basic `forEach` code like the below code.

```kotlin
val array = arrayOf(1, 2)
val list = listOf(1, 2)

array.forEach(::println)
list.forEach(::println)
```

However, if you decompile it in Java, the implementation method of `forEach` differs depending on Array and List.

```java
Integer[] array = new Integer[]{ 1, 2 };
List list = CollectionsKt.listOf(new Integer[]{ 1, 2 });
Integer[] var4 = array;
int var5 = array.length;

int p1;
for(p1 = 0; p1 < var5; ++p1) {
    Object element $iv = var4[p1];
    int p1 =((Number) element $iv).intValue();
    System.out.println(p1);
}

Iterable $this$forEach$iv = (Iterable)list;
Iterator var11 = $this$forEach$iv.iterator();

while(var11.hasNext()) {
    Object element $iv = var11.next();
    p1 = ((Number) element $iv).intValue();
    System.out.println(p1);
}
```

As a result of checking the implementation method of `forEach`, both were implemented in the same `for (element in this) action(element)` method.

```kotlin
public inline fun <T> Array<out T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}

public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}
```

I've been searching for the difference between Array and List to find out why Array and List implementation differently in `in`, but I haven't found anything related to the `in` keyword. Why does the implementation of in look different for Array and List?

Comment: Well, have you tried using the list implementation with an array or vice versa? Arrays don't implement `Iterable`, and lists don't have byte code for element access... the JLS described this for the enhanced for loop: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: Array works the same as Array in Java, and List extends `Iterable`.

Comment: That's exactly my point. You can't use the `Iterable`-based code with an array because it doesn't implement `Iterable`, and you can't use the array-based code with a list because it isn't an array. What lower-level implementation would you expect to work for both a list and an array? The `for` loop effectively abstracts away those differences, but you shouldn't be surprised to see the differences in the implementation byte code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expected that the code translated to something like:

```
for (Integer element: array) {
    System.out.println(element);
}

for (Integer element: list) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Right? However, note that these for loops in Java are [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). These loops are exactly the same as (and this is what the Java compiler will translate those loops to):

```
Integer[] a = array;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    Integer element = a[i];
    System.out.println(element);
}

for (Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer element = (Integer) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Noticed how even in Java, arrays and iterables are translated differently. This is specified in the [Java Language Specification Section 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2). The reason for this is because arrays do not have an `iterator` method in Java (so cannot use the second form), and `Iterable`s can't be indexed with `[]` (so cannot use the first form).

The other differences that you see are mostly due to type erasure, which is why you see casts inserted everywhere, and the implementation details of the decompiler you used. Notice that the second for loop for the list can also be written as the while loop that you see

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer element = (Integer) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Since your decompiler only has the byte code to look at, the question of whether this loop was actually a for loop or a while loop is rather moot.